Boolean returns true if one of two conditions are true, only returns true for the second condition
My function is supposed to work this way:

An if statement in TeamDetailsActivity checks if a boolean is true.
To check this, a DatabaseHelper runs the function isReviewUnallowed.
To do this, it is passed a Team object and a String. The String is the username of whoever is currently logged into the program. An entry with the exact properties of Team exists in a table of teams in the database.
The database checks in a table of team reviews to see if either: A) The team was created by the logged-in user, or B) the logged-in user has already left a review for this team.
If either of those conditions are true, the Database Helper function returns "true." Otherwise, it returns "false."
If the boolean is true, a button in the view for TeamDetailsActivity turns light grey. Otherwise, the button is yellow.
I'm testing my function with two teams and one user. The first team is one that that user created. The other is one that this user didn't make, but they did leave a review for it.
Whenever I test my function, the second condition flags as true when I'm looking at the second team, but the first condition never flags as true for the first team.

Here's the code for TeamDetailsActivity:
package com.example.cecil_finalproject;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.activity.EdgeToEdge;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;
import androidx.core.graphics.Insets;
import androidx.core.view.ViewCompat;
import androidx.core.view.WindowInsetsCompat;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class TeamDetailsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    TextView txtJDetails_header, txtJDetails_avg;
    ListView lvlJDetails_team, lvlJDetails_reviews;
    Button btnJDetails_back, btnJDetails_Review;
    ImageButton imgJDetails_battle;

    DatabaseHelper dbHelper;
    ArrayList<Pokemon> allPokemon = new ArrayList<>();
    pkmnDetailsAdapter detailsAdapterA;
    ArrayList<Review> thisTeamsReviews = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        EdgeToEdge.enable(this);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_team_details);

        //Connect GUI elements
        txtJDetails_header = findViewById(R.id.txtVTeamDetails_username);
        lvlJDetails_team = findViewById(R.id.lvVTeamDetails_team);
        txtJDetails_avg = findViewById(R.id.txtVTeamDetails_average);
        btnJDetails_back = findViewById(R.id.btnVdetails_back);
        imgJDetails_battle = findViewById(R.id.imgVDetails);
        btnJDetails_Review = findViewById(R.id.btnVdetails_review);
        lvlJDetails_reviews = findViewById(R.id.lvVTeamDetails_reviews);

        dbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);
        dbHelper.initAllTables();

        Intent cameFrom = getIntent();
        String loggedUser = (String) cameFrom.getSerializableExtra("Username:");

        Team teamCaught = (Team) cameFrom.getSerializableExtra("Team clicked:");
        //Change the TextView at the top to display the current user's username
        String teamUser = teamCaught.getUserTrainer();
        txtJDetails_header.setText("Team by " + teamUser);

        Integer teamID = teamCaught.getTeamID();

        //Fill the array list of reviews
        thisTeamsReviews = dbHelper.oneTeamsReviews(teamCaught);

        txtJDetails_avg.setText(dbHelper.averageRating(teamID) + " / 5");

        //Step 0: make review button grey and unusable if a review from the current user already exists NOTE TO SELF NOT DONE
        if (dbHelper.isReviewUnallowed(teamCaught, loggedUser) == true) {
            //make button grey (#E0E0E0)
            //I went to colors.xml and added both yellow and light grey. NOTE TO SELF CHECK WITH TEACHER IF THAT'S ALLOWED
            btnJDetails_Review.setBackgroundTintList(ContextCompat.getColorStateList(this, R.color.light_grey));
        }
        else {
            //make button yellow again (#FDCE40)
            btnJDetails_Review.setBackgroundTintList(ContextCompat.getColorStateList(this, R.color.yellow));
            //Only call the listener for the review button if the boolean is false
            detailsReviewListener();
        }

        //Step 1: create and call button listeners
        detailsBackListener();
        detailsBattleListener();

        //Step 2: add all the Pokemon in the team to an array list of Pokemon using the database helper
        allPokemon = dbHelper.pkmnOnTeam(teamID);

        //Step 3: add a review if the current user just gave one NOTE TO SELF NOT DONE

        //Step 4: populate the first list view
        fillFirstList();

        //Step 5: populate second list view NOTE TO SELF NOT DONE
    }

    private void detailsBackListener() {
        btnJDetails_back.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent cameFrom = getIntent();
                String loggedUser = (String) cameFrom.getSerializableExtra("Username:");

                Intent detailsToWelcome = new Intent(TeamDetailsActivity.this, WelcomeActivity.class);
                detailsToWelcome.putExtra("Username:", loggedUser);
                startActivity(detailsToWelcome);
            }
        });
    }

    private void detailsBattleListener() {
        imgJDetails_battle.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent cameFrom = getIntent();
                String loggedUser = (String) cameFrom.getSerializableExtra("Username:");
                Team teamCaught = (Team) cameFrom.getSerializableExtra("Team clicked:");

                Intent detailsToBattle = new Intent(TeamDetailsActivity.this, BattleChooseActivity.class);
                detailsToBattle.putExtra("Username:", loggedUser);
                detailsToBattle.putExtra("Team clicked:", teamCaught);
                startActivity(detailsToBattle);
            }
        });
    }

    private void detailsReviewListener() {
        btnJDetails_Review.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent cameFrom = getIntent();
                String loggedUser = (String) cameFrom.getSerializableExtra("Username:");
                Team teamCaught = (Team) cameFrom.getSerializableExtra("Team clicked:");

                Intent detailsToReview = new Intent(TeamDetailsActivity.this, LeaveReviewActivity.class);
                detailsToReview.putExtra("Username:", loggedUser);
                detailsToReview.putExtra("Team clicked:", teamCaught);
                startActivity(detailsToReview);
            }
        });
    }

    public void fillFirstList() {
        detailsAdapterA = new pkmnDetailsAdapter(this, allPokemon);
        lvlJDetails_team.setAdapter(detailsAdapterA);
    }
}

Here's the code for my DatabaseHelper: https://pastebin.com/RqqsZFBD
I ran out of space to paste my code, so here's a pastebin link.

"I ran out of space" is a strong hint that this is not a [mre]
